# Caching JSON - Haneke get fetch values

Tags: ios, json, swift, caching

I am not able assign the values for var backgroundArray and var newsArray, as the fetch method returns nil. Within the fetch the values are available though. Also, is it a good way to refresh the cache by removing it such way in the commented section?

```
init(update: Bool){

    let dataurl = "http://example.com"
    let imgurl = "http://example.com"

    let newsDataURL = NSURL(string: dataurl)!
    let backgroundURL = NSURL(string: imgurl)!

    var backgroundArray = [JSON]()
    var newsArray = [JSON]()

    let cache = Shared.JSONCache

//        if update{
//            cache.remove(key: dataurl)
//            cache.remove(key: imgurl)
//        }

    cache.fetch(URL: newsDataURL).onSuccess { json in
        let data = json.asData()
        newsArray = JSON(data: data).arrayValue
    }

    cache.fetch(URL: backgroundURL).onSuccess{ json in
        let data = json.asData()
        backgroundArray = JSON(data: data).arrayValue
    }

    populateStories(newsArray, backgroundArray: backgroundArray)
}
```